# Map not unpacking tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I have this simple formula that converts an IP to a 32 bits integer:

```
(first octet * 256**3) + (second octet * 256**2) + (third octet * 256**1) + (fourth octet)
```

I made a program that does that:

```
def ip_to_int32(ip):
    # split values
    ip = ip.split(".")

    # formula to convert to 32, x is the octet, y is the power
    to_32 = lambda x, y: int(x) * 256** (3 - y)

    # Sum it all to have the int32 of the ip
    # reversed is to give the correct power to octet
    return sum(
        to_32(octet, pwr) for pwr, octet in enumerate(ip)
    )

 ip_to_int32("128.32.10.1") # --> 2149583361
```

And it works as intended.

Then I tried to make a one-liner, just for the sake of doing it.

```
sum(map(lambda x, y: int(x) * 256 ** (3 - y), enumerate(ip.split("."))))
```

But this raises

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So the tuple (y, x) is not being unpacked. I can fix this with

```
sum(map(lambda x: int(x[1]) * 256 ** (3 - x[0]), enumerate(ip.split("."))))
```

But this seems uglier (one liners are always ugly)

I even tried using a list comprehensions, but map still doesn't unpack the values.

**Is this a feature or am I doing something wrong? Is there a specific way to do this?**

Comment: I think you're using `map()` when what you really want is `reduce()`.

Comment: The lambda function should be `lambda (x, y): int(x) * 256 ** (3 - y)` -- `lambda x, y` is equivalent to `def (x, y):`: you are defining a function that takes two arguments, rather than a single tuple.

Comment: @PascalBugnion: that works on Python 2, but that feature was removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is probably a little tidier (using `reduce()` as I suggested in my comment)

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a * 256 + int(b), ip.split("."), 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

True, `map` doesn't unpack, but [starmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) does:

```
sum(starmap(lambda x, y: int(y) * 256 ** (3 - x), enumerate(ip.split("."))))
```

Comment: requires `from itertools import starmap` statement

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent generator expression would be

```
>>> ip = "128.32.10.1"
>>> sum(int(base) * 256 ** (3 - exp) for exp, base in enumerate(ip.split('.')))
2149583361
```